# Ad not showing on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I'm targetting my app for phones and tablets. I've created a `fragments.xml` on `/layout` and on `/layout-land`.

On the class that manages the fragments I've put this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragments);

    adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentsboth) != null) {
        numberOfPanes = 1;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        QueryFragment firstFragment = new QueryFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentsboth, firstFragment).commit();
    } else if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        QueryFragment firstFragment = new QueryFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_one, firstFragment).commit();
        if (operation != 5) {
            Infodata secondFragment = new Infodata();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_two, secondFragment).commit();
        } else {
            Compare secondFragment = new Compare();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_two, secondFragment).commit();
        }
    }
    }
```

I've added the `AdView` to both of my `fragments.xml` and it is working as expected on the phone. The ad is show.

On the tablet, I can see the space for the ad but no add is show.

Here is the code from `fragments.xml` for the tablets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightgrey">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/lightgrey"
            android:baselineAligned="false">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/lightgrey">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:baselineAligned="false">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_two"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                        android:id="@+id/adView"
                        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        ads:adUnitId="12121212"
                        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/orange"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/menulist_selector"
            android:background="@color/lblack"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Why isn't the ad shown?**

Comment: LogCat shows some warning about ad space?

Comment: Yep :) You are right. No add space. Can this be solved? `Not enough space to show ad. Needs 800x119, but only has 534x1108`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When LogCat displays something like:

```
WARN/Ads(3805): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <xxx, xx>, Has: <xxx, xx>.
```

it means the Ad has no space to be displayed. Your `Layout` is occupying all the height on the view. So even if you specifies AdView in your layot, It is getting 0 height.

Comment: Thanks. Removed `SMART_BANNER` and substituted by `BANNER` and it now works. One problem though. If I disconnect from the network, the ad space is still there. How can I change my layout so that when there is network, the ad is shown without overlapping any content and with no network, the `@+id/LinearLayout01` or the `@+id/fragment_two` takes all the height of the screen?

Comment: You should implement adlistener and onAdFailedToLoad method: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdFailedToLoad(int) If you receive an error, remove the view from the UI (remove or hide with visibility.HIDDEN